# deployment fails to recreate a successful replicaset

Tags: deployment, kubectl, replicaset

We are using Kubernetes 1.8 to deploy our software in a cloud provider. Frequently, when deploying a specific pod-template, the deployment fails to create a successful replicaset and no instance is created. I am not able to find a better description than kubectl describe deploy.

```
  Type           Status  Reason
  ----           ------  ------
  Available      False   MinimumReplicasUnavailable
  Progressing    False   ProgressDeadlineExceeded
OldReplicaSets:  <none>
NewReplicaSet:   <none>
Events:
  Type    Reason             Age               From                   Message
  ----    ------             ----              ----                   -------
  Normal  ScalingReplicaSet  21m (x3 over 2d)  deployment-controller  Scaled up replica set cbase-d-6bbfbdb5dc to 1
  Normal  ScalingReplicaSet  19m (x3 over 2d)  deployment-controller  Scaled down replica set cbase-d-6bbfbdb5dc to 0
```

Answer (score 10):

also you can check the status of the replicaet:

```
kubectl describe replicaset cbase-d-6bbfbdb5dc
```

hope you will find the conditions and the reason why the replicaset could not be scaled up

Answer (score 5):

While this might not be always true but a likely reason could be the unavailability of resources. Try increasing the resources (cpu+memory) allocated to the cluster.

This was exactly the error I got and increasing allocated resources fixed the issue (on GKE).

Answer (score 5):

I got a similar error like yours yesterday and finally figured out that I could get error message from the pod corresponds with the deployment by using command `kubectl get pod YOUR_POD_NAME -o yaml`. You can check the status and error message there.