# kubernetes deployment fails during deployment

Tags: nginx, kubernetes, cluster-computing

I have Kubernetes cluster with a master and a two workers.

```
$ kubectl get nodes
NAME      STATUS   ROLES    AGE   VERSION
master    Ready    master   54d   v1.18.4
worker1   Ready    <none>   2d    v1.18.4
worker2   Ready    <none>   45h   v1.18.4
```

Then I have used `kubectl create deployment nginx --image=nginx`

And then checked

```
$ kubectl get deployment
NAME             READY   UP-TO-DATE   AVAILABLE   AGE
nginx            0/1     1            0           117m
```

```
$ kubectl describe deployment nginx
.
.
.
Type           Status  Reason
  ----           ------  ------
  Available      False   MinimumReplicasUnavailable
  Progressing    False   ProgressDeadlineExceeded
```

I have enough hardware resources unlike [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48954357/deployment-fails-to-recreate-a-successful-replicaset).

```
$ kubectl get events

12m         Warning   Failed                    pod/nginx-f89759699-qxbwc             Failed to pull image "docker.io/istio/proxyv2:1.5.2": rpc error: code = Unknown desc = Error response from daemon: Get https://registry-1.docker.io/v2/: net/http: request canceled while waiting for connection (Client.Timeout exceeded while awaiting headers)
12m         Warning   Failed                    pod/nginx-f89759699-qxbwc             Error: ErrImagePull
11m         Normal    BackOff                   pod/nginx-f89759699-qxbwc             Back-off pulling image "docker.io/istio/proxyv2:1.5.2"
4m47s       Warning   Failed                    pod/nginx-f89759699-qxbwc             Error: ImagePullBackOff
28m         Normal    SandboxChanged            pod/productpage-v1-7f44c4d57c-sklfh   Pod sandbox changed, it will be killed and re-created.
```

I had a single node cluster, recently added two worker nodes to the cluster using `kubeadm`, would that be a problem?

I also noticed something, My cluster loses internet connectivity soon after worker nodes join cluster.

```
$route -n

Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         192.168.100.1    0.0.0.0         UG    100    0        0 ens32
172.17.0.0      0.0.0.0          255.255.0.0     U     0      0        0 docker0
192.168.100.0   0.0.0.0          255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 ens32
192.168.100.1   192.168.100.222  255.255.255.255 UGH   0      0        0 tunl0
```

Here `192.168.100.1` is my network gateway and `192.168.100.222` is Master IP.
This is my first kubernetes cluster works. So I may have done a mistake. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: any other image works? You have reachability to internet to pull image from docker?

Comment: @ArghyaSadhu Yes, I have `istio-sample` application running successfully. I forgot to mention, I have used single node cluster, recently added two worker nodes. I will update it in the question.

Comment: Try running docker pull nginx from the nodes and see if that works

Comment: @JulianoCosta cant be, as I its just normal `nginx`

Comment: As @ArghyaSadhu mentioned, `docker pull` works both on your master and workers? Do you use any [proxy](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubeadm/issues/1201#issuecomment-494686022)? If you create nginx with `kubectl apply` it works or not?

Comment: The error message is not showing nginx image but "docker.io/istio/proxyv2:1.5.2", can you add the deployment definition file on the question?

Comment: @jt97 yes, `docker pull nginx` works. I have tested. But still same state.